# How in master page to show/hide placeholder based on page layout content type?

Tags: master-page, content-type

How is the best approch to show / hide place holders which are in the Master Page based on which content type the Page Layout is associated with?

In the design we have a right placeholder for all article page layouts, but for start pages which are associated with the welcome page we want to hide the right placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the placeholder's visible tag to false

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="whatevertheidis" Visible="false">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: u cant set visibility false for contentplaceholder's, it will make some javascipt error..place this contentplaceholder inside one panel and make that panel visibility false to hide the placeholder.